# Current location in codenameone is null

Tags: location, codenameone

I use the following code to take current location of mobile in codename

Location location = LocationManager.getLocationManager()
                    .getCurrentLocationSync(60000);

And i test it on Android mobile it always show location is null

Also in simulator it gives 
 latitude 40.715353
 longitude -74.00497299999999

How to solve this problem and get current gps position of mobile?

Answer (score 0):

The simulator has the ability to simulate locations in the latest version you can point at the location you want to simulate.

Null will be returned if a location isn't available, you can query the status of the GPS based on that. Make sure your GPS is turned on.